# React table data and state does not persist, from

Tags: reactjs, persistence, react-table

I am new in react & react table,

How can I make react table and state persist accross sesshions.

I could make it persist in a non clean way. Using reverse engoneering and localStorage.

I am sure there is a clean way. Can someone send me a link with a doc or example.

Answer (score 0):

you have to store your table data in localStorage.